# Variable $term_id doesn't show up in get_term_meta function from wordpress

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I would like to show values from custom fields in my Post Categories in Wordpress. To do this, I have used some code in my `functions.php` file to add and save these custom fields to the different categories in the Wordpress database. I am running into an issue, when trying to pull the values from the custom fields.

Here's the issue: I am trying to use `get_term_meta` to pull the `term_id` variable on WordPress:

```
echo get_term_meta($term_id, 'site_section_1', true);
```

However, the variable is not showing up when I do this, but it works when I call an individual `$term_id` such as:

```
echo get_term_meta(47, 'site_section_1', true);
```

My database table looks something like this:

```
meta id    term_id    meta_key                  meta_value
    1          47     site_section_1            Blog Category
    2          47     site_subsection_1         Events Stories
    3          47     department_1              Events
    4          48     site_section_1            Blog Category
    5          48     site_subsection_1         Communications Stories
    6          48     department_1              Communications
```

I have added this code to the `functions.php` file to add custom fields to Post Categories:

```
function wcr_category_fields($term) {
if (current_filter() == 'category_edit_form_fields') {
    $site_section_1 = get_term_meta($term->term_id, 'site_section_1', true);
    $site_subsection_1 = get_term_meta($term->term_id, 'site_subsection_1', true);
    $department_1 = get_term_meta($term->term_id, 'department_1', true);
    ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th valign="top" scope="row"><label for="term_fields[site_section_1]"><?php _e('Site Section'); ?></label></th>
        <td>
              <input type="text" size="40" value="<?php echo esc_attr($site_section_1); ?>" id="term_fields[site_section_1]" name="term_fields[site_section_1]"><br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th valign="top" scope="row"><label for="term_fields[site_subsection_1]"><?php _e('Site Subsection'); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" size="40" value="<?php echo esc_attr($site_subsection_1); ?>" id="term_fields[site_subsection_1]" name="term_fields[site_subsection_1]"><br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th valign="top" scope="row"><label for="term_fields[department_1]"><?php _e('Department'); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" size="40" value="<?php echo esc_attr($department_1); ?>" id="term_fields[department_1]" name="term_fields[department_1]"><br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php } elseif (current_filter() == 'category_add_form_fields') {
    ?>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="term_fields[site_section_1]"><?php _e('site_section_1'); ?></label>
        <input type="text" size="40" value="" id="term_fields[site_section_1]" name="term_fields[site_section_1]">
    </div>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="term_fields[site_subsection_1]"><?php _e('site_subsection_1'); ?></label>
        <input type="text" size="40" value="" id="term_fields[site_subsection_1]" name="term_fields[site_subsection_1]">
    </div>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="term_fields[department_1]"><?php _e('department_1'); ?></label>
        <input type="text" size="40" value="" id="term_fields[department_1]" name="term_fields[department_1]">
    </div>
<?php
}
}

add_action('category_add_form_fields', 'wcr_category_fields', 10, 2);
add_action('category_edit_form_fields', 'wcr_category_fields', 10, 2);

function wcr_save_category_fields($term_id) {
    if (!isset($_POST['term_fields'])) {
        return;
    }

    foreach ($_POST['term_fields'] as $key => $value) {
        update_term_meta($term_id, $key, sanitize_text_field($value));
    }
}
add_action('edited_category', 'wcr_save_category_fields', 10, 2);
add_action('create_category', 'wcr_save_category_fields', 10, 2);
```

Please, let me know, if you need any other information.

Comment: where you used the provided code? why the variable not defined?

Comment: Hi @SamvelAleqsanyan Thanks for the response. I added the code in my header.php file. and the database table is in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: can you provide the code of `header.php`  file( edit your question and add there )?

Comment: I am trying to pull the $term_id variable from the database, so for now, the only code I have relevant to this in the header.php file is the echo statement I put above.

Comment: it's unclear for me, where you defined `$term_id`? in the provided code there is nothing related. what is your goal?

Comment: Thanks @SamvelAleqsanyan. I tried to clarify my goal in the new edits. Basically, I am trying to pull values from these custom fields I created in the Posts Categories on Wordpress. So for now, I would like to display 'Events Stories' for the Events Category or 'Communications Stories' for the Communications Category.

Comment: ok. the provided code looks ok. do you want to use `$term_id` variable from one of provided functions?

Comment: Hi @SamvelAleqsanyan, thanks so much, you were really helpful. I'm a beginner in php, so realized my mistake when you told me I needed to define $term_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out, how to do this in case anyone else needs this:

I didn't define `$term_id`, and I also needed to attach it with the category. So, I used the `get_the_category` function to pull the `term_id`, and then I used that as the variable in the `get_term_meta` function:

```
<?php
$categories = get_the_category();
    if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
        $term_id = $categories[0]->term_id;
        echo $term_id;
        echo get_term_meta($term_id, 'site_section_1', true);
        echo get_term_meta($term_id, 'site_subsection_1', true);
        echo get_term_meta($term_id, 'department', true);
    }
?>
```